# SQL Case Statement to Determine Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having this issue here.  I am trying to use a case statement to determine which filter to use.  It is OK to use it for single values, but it is not OK to use a Select Statement results.

```
DECLARE @SingleValue INT = 0

SELECT 
    t1.Field1
    , t1.Field2
    , t1.Field3
FROM 
    tblTable1 t1
    INNER JOIN tblTable2 t2 ON t1.Field1 = t2.Field
WHERE 
    t1.Field2 IN (SELECT CASE WHEN @SingleValue = 0 THEN (SELECT Field1 FROM tblTable3) ELSE t1.Field2 END)
    AND t2.Field2 = (CASE WHEN @SingleValue = 0 THEN t2.Field2 ELSE @SingleValue END)
```

Once the @singleValue is set to a value '123' then it is working fine, the moment when I set the value to '0' (ZERO) then it returns an error 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'

The problem start with '(SELECT Field1 FROM tblTable3)' in the case statement. How can I work around it to get multiple values in the case statement.

Thanks.

Comment: Use AND / OR instead if a case...

Comment: Have you considered adding a `LIMIT`?

Comment: "to get multiple values in the case statement" - you don't. a `CASE` *expression*, in common with other expressions in SQL, is intended to produce a *single* value (per row for which it is evaluated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
DECLARE @SingleValue INT = 0

SELECT 
    t1.Field1
    , t1.Field2
    , t1.Field3
FROM 
    tblTable1 t1
    INNER JOIN tblTable2 t2 ON t1.Field1 = t2.Field
WHERE 
    (
        ( @SingleValue <> 0 )
        or
        ( t1.Field2 IN ( SELECT Field1 FROM tblTable3) )
    )
    and
    (
        ( @SingleValue = 0 )
        or
        ( t2.Field2 = @SingleValue )
    )
```